# Mysql Custom select query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have these 2 mysql queryes

```
SELECT `name` AS name1,`id` AS id1 FROM `table` WHERE id=1
SELECT `name` AS name2,`id` AS name2 FROM `table` WHERE id=2
```

The results will be outputed like this

```
NAME1  ID1
john  1
NAME2  ID2
meg   2
```

Is there anyway that from 2 queries I would make 1 and it will show all results on 1 line from same table ?

```
NAME1   ID1  NAME2   ID2
john     1   meg     2
```

Comment: There is a way it can be done but it would be very ugly and very unorthodox. Can you elucidate the reason why you can't query like in the responses provided below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select tbl1.name,tbl1.id,tbl2.name,tbl2.id from mytable tbl1,mytable tbl2

but this query would be a mess, it will give you the whole combinations of two names in any order from your table, you could filter it with a WHERE clause but.. how many names do you have?? why doing that? maybe if we know what you're trying to do we might give you a better answer

**EDIT** ohhh i see your queries now... it should be something like this

```
select tbl1.name,tbl1.id,tbl2.name,tbl2.id from mytable tbl1,mytable tbl2  where tbl1.id=1 and tbl2.id=2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.name AS name1, t1.id AS id1, t2.name as name2, t2.id as id2
FROM table as t1, table as t2 WHERE t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Min( Case When Id = 1 Then Id End ) As Id1
    , Min( Case When Id = 1 Then Name End ) As Name1
    , Min( Case When Id = 2 Then Id End ) As Id2
    , Min( Case When Id = 2 Then Name End ) As Name2
From `table`
Where Id In(1,2)
```

Comment: A curious down-vote. I'd be fascinated to know the reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like using OR in the WHERE clause? Like:

```
SELECT `name`,`id` FROM `table` WHERE id=1 OR id = 2
```

Comment: This would produce two rows tho.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the query like this

```
SELECT `name`,`id` FROM `table` WHERE id=1 OR id=2
```

but, you'll still get two results. What are you trying to do with the result output?